Finite generativity of algebra with valuation
Let $C$ be a commutative finitely generated algebra with no zero divisors. If necessary, we can assume it to be graded and a unique factorization domain. Let $a\in C$ be a prime element.
Let's also consider a valuation $v$ of $\operatorname{Quot}(C)$ with valuation group $\mathbb{Z}$, $v(a) = 1$, $v(C) \geqslant 0$ and the following algebra:
$$C' = C\left[{\scriptsize\frac{1}{a}}\right]\cap\{f\in\operatorname{Quot}(C) \mid v(f) \geqslant 0\}.$$
One may assume $C'$ is also graded and a UFD.
Question: Will $C'$ be finitely generated under these conditions?
Some thoughts: We can represent $C'$ as
$$C' = C\cup I_1\!\cdot\!{\scriptsize\frac{1}{a}}\cup I_2\!\cdot\!{\scriptsize\frac{1}{a^2}}\cup\dotsb,$$
where $I_k = \{c\in C\mid v(c)\geqslant k\}\vartriangleleft C.$
I've heard that in algebraic geometry there is a standard construction (blowing up of the subvariety with defining ideal $I_1$ in $\operatorname{Spec}(C)$) which shows that for the algebra
$$C\cup I_1\!\cdot\!{\scriptsize\frac{1}{a}}\cup I^2_1\!\cdot\!{\scriptsize\frac{1}{a^2}}\cup I^3_1\!\cdot\!{\scriptsize\frac{1}{a^3}}\cup\dots$$
the answer is "Yes". But in my case $I^k_1\subsetneq I_k$.

Welcome new user.  Let $C$ be $\mathbb{C}[a,b]$.  For every element $f=f(a,b)$ in $C$, let $v(f)$ be the zero order (at $z=0$) of the holomorphic function $f(z,ze^z)$.  Thus, $C'$ contains elements $c_1=b/a, c_2=(b-a)/a^2, c_3=(b-(a+a^2/2))/a^3, \dots, c_{n+1}=(b-(a+a^2/2 + \dots + a^n/n!))/a^{n+1},\dots$

@JasonStarr Thanks for the answer!
I have a small pedantic remark that since $ze^z = z + z^2 + z^3/2 + \dots + z^n/(n-1)!+\dots$, then the correct expression for $c_{n+1}$ should be $(b - (a + a^2 + a^3/2+\dots + a^n/(n-1)!))/a^{n+1}.$ But, of course, that doesn't change anything at all.
You seem to have given an excellent example of a non finitely generated algebra that satisfies all the conditions above. Unfortunately, I am still struggling to strictly prove that we can't find a finite set of elements of $C'$ that generates all $c_n$.

You are correct.  Thank you for the correction.

$C'$ is the union of $a^{-k} I_k$ over all nonnegative integers $k$, rather than the direct sum, is it not?  Every element of $C[a^{-1}]$ is of the form $c/a^k$ for some $c \in C$ and some nonnegative integer $k$, which lies in $C'$ if and only if $c \in I_k$.  Note, for example, that $C$ and $a^{-1}I_1$ both contain $1$ and therefore are not disjoint.

Also, it's not clear what $v(a) = 1$ means, unless you mean that the valuation group of $v$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.  But, in that case, $I_1 = (a)$ and $C' = C[a^{-1}] \cap C_{(a)} = C$.

@JesseElliott your comment on $v(a) = 1$ is fair, the condition on the valuation group should be not an additional assumption, but a requirement.
I didn't get you second sentence. In general case $C'$ is often strictly larger than $C$. Even in the example provided above by Jason Starr, neither $I_1 = (a)$ nor $C' = C$.

Ah, sorry.  I was confusing $I_1$ with ${f \in \text{Quot}(C): v(f) \geq 1}$ in the valuation overing, which is generated by $a$.  I still think that the prior comment stands, namely, that $C' = \bigcup_k a^{-k}I_k$, rather than $C' = \oplus_k a^{-k}I_k$.

@JesseElliott yeah, you're right, the sum isn't direct, that's another my blunder. I will edit the question and hope there won't be more missleading things. Thank you.

@LSpice yes, that's a typo..

The blowup you refer to is the affine blowup algebra $C\left[\frac{I_1}{a}\right]$, rather than the blowup algebra, or Rees algebra.  See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/052P

There is a counterexample when $C'$ won't be finitely generated. The example was suggested by Jason Starr in the comments above.
Let $C$ be $\mathbb{C}[a, b]$ and, for every element $f(a, b)\in C$, let $v(f)$ be the zero order at $z = 0$ of the holomorphic function $f(z, ze^z)$.
In this case,
$$I_{n+1} = \left(b - a - a^2 - {\small\frac{a^3}{2}} - \dots - \frac{a^n}{(n-1)!},\quad\!\!\! a^{n+1}\right),\quad n = 0,1, 2, \dots.$$
Indeed, it is easy to verify that both elements lie in $I_{n+1}$ and for each $f\in I_{n+1}$ we can think of it as an element of $(\mathbb{C}[a])[b]$ and decompose $f$ by powers of $b - a - a^2-\dots -a^{n}/(n-1)!.$ Then we get that the constant term, which is a polynomial solely of $a$, lies in $I_{n+1}$. Therefore, it is divisible by $a^{n+1}$.
We obtain $\mathbb{C}[I_{n+1}\cdot {\small \frac{1}{a^{n+1}}}] = \mathbb{C}[c_{n+1}, a]$,  where $c_{n+1} = {\frac{b - a - a^2 - \dots - a^{n}/(n-1)!}{a^{n+1}}}, \quad\!\!\! c_1 = b.$
Assume $C'$ has a finite set of generators. Since $C\subset I_1\cdot {\small\frac{1}{a}}\subset I_2\cdot {\small\frac{1}{a^2}}\subset\dotsb$, then we can suppose that all generators belong to $I_N\cdot {\small\frac{1}{a^N}}$ for a certain $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Let's prove $c_{N+1}\notin \mathbb{C}[I_N\cdot {\small \frac{1}{a^N}}] = \mathbb{C}[c_N, a]$.
Suppose the opposite $c_{N+1} \in \mathbb{C}[c_N, a]$, i.e. there exists a polynomial $P(x, y)$ such that
$$P(c_N, a) = c_{N+1} = \frac{c_N - {\small \frac{a^N}{(N-1)!}}}{a}$$
$$aP(c_N, a) = c_N - {\small \frac{a^N}{(N-1)!}}.$$
Since polynomials in the left-hand and right-hand sides are different (look at the coefficients of $c_N^1$), we have an algebraic dependency between $c_N$ and $a$. Multiplying this algebraic dependency by some power of $a$ we obtain an algebraic dependency between $b$ and $a$. So, $c_{N+1}\notin \mathbb{C}[c_N, a]$ and $C'$ has no finite set of generators.
